# Visual Studio Projects Setup

Tags: projects-and-solutions

Trying to work out the best way to organise my Visual Studio solution.

We currently have a class library project that contains all our business logic, services and repositories etc. The main consumer of this is a separate MVC 5 project. We are about to add an api to this solution and we're wondering whether this should be added in as a separate project or just include it within the MVC project?

Comment: Will this API be deployed separately from the MVC website?

Comment: @MichaelBenford To be honest not decided, was thinking that would depend on whether we had it as a separate project.